# Flask app on Vercel gives 404 error when deployed

Tags: python, flask, deployment, vercel

I have a Flask app that I am trying to deploy on Vercel. However, when I visit the URL of the deployed app, I get a 404 error. I have tried adjusting the Vercel configuration file vercel.json and the Flask app app.py, but I am still encountering the error.

Here is my file structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZBG6.jpg

Here is my vercel.json file:

```
{
  "env": {
      "FLASK_ENV": "production"
  },
  "routes": [
      {
          "src": "/static/(.*)",
          "dest": "../static/$1"
      },
      {
          "src": "/templates/(.*)",
          "dest": "../templates/$1"
      },
      {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "/api/$1"
      }
  ]
}
```

And here is my app.py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, session, redirect
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
from flask_session import Session
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("u thought lol")
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../../static', template_folder='../../templates')
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
Session(app)
db = client.get_database('chatUser')
chatUser = db.chatUsers
messageDB = db.messageDB
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")



@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if 'username' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('chat'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        username_found = chatUser.find_one({"username": username})
        if username_found:
            user_val = username_found['username']
            passwordcheck = username_found['password']
            session["username"] = user_val
            session['password'] = passwordcheck
            return redirect(url_for('chat'))
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chat():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    messages = []
    chatRefreshDisplay = messageDB.find({})
    for message in chatRefreshDisplay:
        messages.append((message['name'], message['Chat']))

    @socketio.on('message')
    def handleMessage(msg):
        print('Message' + msg)
        broad = send(msg, broadcast=True)
        username1 = session['username']
        messageDBSend = {'name': username1, 'Chat': msg}
        messageDB.insert_one(messageDBSend)
        messages.append((username1, msg))

    return render_template("chat.html", username1=session["username"], messages=messages)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 3000))
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I have checked the logs on Vercel and I can't seem to find any errors that are causing the issue.

Does anyone know why it isn't Working

app: https://friendchat101-kmsrjcqin-avyukt-ballari.vercel.app/

Answer (score 2):

Flask doesn't work nicely with Vercel but it can be done. They have an example that you can match the configuration of: https://vercel.com/templates/python/flask-hello-world

---

You need to configure your `Output Directory` on Vercel.

- Go to the project Settings. For `Output Directory`, it says 'public'
  if it exists, or '.'.
  You can try using `.` here. I had to put `api/templates`. That's where
  all the frontend HTML files live.

Update your file structure so that app.py can find the templates by default. `templates`, `static`, and `school` should all be in `api`.

```
api 
   app.py
   school/
   static/
   templates/
requirements
vercel.json
```

Then update `vercel.json`. You have 2 options:

- Option 1 is most commonly found in online tutorials:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./api/app.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Option 2 is the exact match from Vercel's example:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api/index" }]
}
```

Lastly, remove the last 3 lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 3000))
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```